# Thermostatically controlled hot plate on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat

I've heard that it's forbidden to use a thermostatically controlled hot plate on Shabbat. I understand why it would be forbidden in the case of liquids, but does this also apply to fully-cooked dry foods?

Comment: "I understand why it would be forbidden in the case of liquids" Could you tell us the reason? Editing in relevant information can help others answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard that it's forbidden to use a thermostatically controlled hot plate on Shabbat.

That would make sense, as putting cold items on it would kick in the heating mechanism.

> I understand why it would be forbidden in the case of liquids, but does this also apply to fully-cooked dry foods?

Based on the reasoning, it would make no difference if you put on solids, liquids or an empty cold pot.

Comment: Where "cold' means anything below the target temperature of the hot plate.